# Can't see my windows names in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: Like this]

I tried to reopen, swipe it but to no avail.

Comment: Try this: Window -> Editor Tabs-> Configure Editor Tabs then Tab Placement top

Comment: nothing changed :(

Comment: tried restore default layout ? window->restore default layout

Comment: yep. Didn't make any difference